# How to get an ITypeBinding from a class or interface name (String) with Eclipse JDT ASTParser?

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I would like to find all calls to java.io.Closeable.close(), for this the best would be that I run something like this:

```
    AST ast = compilationUnit.getAST();
    final ITypeBinding closeableTypeBinding = ast.resolveWellKnownType("java.io.Closeable");

    compilationUnit.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
        @Override
        public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {
            String name = node.getName().toString();
            if (! ("close".equals(name) && node.arguments().isEmpty()) ) {
                return true;
            }

            IMethodBinding binding = node.resolveMethodBinding();
            ITypeBinding classBinding = binding.getDeclaringClass();
            if (classBinding.isAssignmentCompatible(closeableTypeBinding)) {
                int lineNumber = compilationUnit.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition());
                printf("Call to %s at %s:%s\n", node, fileName, lineNumber);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

The problem that I have is that ast.resolveWellKnownType() only works for a few pre-hardcoded types and I can't ask for java.io.Closeable.

Is there away to ask the JDT framework to get the ITypeBinding of any class or interface?

**NOTE**: I'm using a standalone program that uses JDT to perform some code inspection. From what I read the usage of JDT outside of eclipse is quite limited, although in my case I'm able to resolve bindings of existing ASTNodes that I have parsed.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `IType` from the binding:

```
IType boundType = (IType)typeBinding.getJavaElement();
```

And compare that with `boundType.equals(otherType)` to the `IType` of the class or interface you want to check. You can get an `IType` object of any class bei either using `IJavaProject.findType(String className)` or with the JDT `SearchEngine`.

To continue you can then use the `IType` to parse the type to an AST model. (At least that's what I think you want to do, otherwise you could just compare the class name with `ITypeBinding.getQualifiedName()`)

Comment: I believe that IJavaProject is only accessible from Eclipse or an Eclipse plugin. A standalone program using JDT doesn't have access to projects or the workbench. Furthermore, getJavaElement() always returns null in my setup. That's the only part that doesn't work for me.